# The following 3rd-party plugin is causing the build to fail and may need to be updated to a newer version: cordova-plugin-speechrecognition

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Anyone else getting this issue on the IOS build when trying to build on phonegap?

**"The following 3rd-party plugin is causing the build to fail and may need to be updated to a newer version: cordova-plugin-speechrecognition"**

this is my line in my config.xml file:

```
 <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-speechrecognition" source="npm" />
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Have you tried to update the plugin?

Comment: When I try build the app on phonegap I ma getting this error on the IOS build: The following 3rd-party plugin is causing the build to fail and may need to be updated to a newer version: cordova-plugin-speechrecognition. The build works fine on the Android build

Comment: Go here https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-speechrecognition/issues, click the new issue button and report the problem. BTW, the plugin requires Xcode 8, probably phonegap build is still using Xcode 7 and that is why the plugin fails to build